# How to install Adobe Digital Editions in Ubutu 22.04.01

Tags: adobe-digital-editions

How to install Adobe Digital Editions in Ubutu 22.04.01?
I saw old posts, from 2019 or before, so maybe things have changed. Is there any way?
Thanks.